# com.codahale.metrics.Timer for timing method execution with CompleteableFuture

Tags: java, time, prometheus, completable-future, codahale-metrics

We are using `com.codahale.metrics.Timer` to time how long it takes for a `completeableFuture` method to finish.

We have this code:

```
import com.codahale.metrics.Timer;
import com.codahale.metrics.MetricRegistry;
...

Timer timer = MetricsRegistry.timer("older-Cat-latency");
Timer.Context context = timer.time();
DeferredResult<OlderCat> deferredResult = new DeferredResult<>();

catService.getOlderCat(catName)
            .handle((result, err) -> {
                if(err != null){
                    deferredResult.setErrorResult(new OlderCat(...));
                    return null;
                }
                context.stop();  <----  // here we stop the timer
                deferredResult.setResult(result);
                return null;
            });

return deferredResult;
```

Theoretically, this code should be OK, but when checking the time in the `Prometheus` we see very low timing latency that doesn't seem to fit with the actual results we get (e.g. 15 Milli-Seconds are measured by the timer, compared to actual 2 Seconds we measure "by hand")

So, it seems like there are two options:

- The code above is not timing correctly
- The code is timing correctly, but the charts in Grafana are somehow misleading.

Do you know if the timing code is correct?

Comment: From documentation, the time is mesured in nanoseconds. A wrong unit specification or a wrong factor is likely. Can't you check in prometheus or scrapping the endpoint by hand ?

Comment: do you get the expected response from this controller? (except the timing)